# Purpose of variables that are of type enum in C

Tags: c, variables, enums

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum week { sunday = 0, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };

int main()
{
    int testNum = monday;
    enum week var = monday;
    printf("%d\n", testNum);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the purpose of making a variable a type of a specific enum?  For example in the code above what is the benefit of the variable var being a type "enum week" vs just having an interger like the "testNum" integer?

Comment: Basically just better debugger support. (Enums are weird like that.) Also possibly scoping (which you can't do with macros).

Comment: Better readability. Better type checking.

Comment: Simpler definitions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Enums have no typesafety advantage over integers in C (only in C++ they do, but even there one conversion direction isn't checked (can't remember which one)).

Comment: @PSkocik C compilers are still emiting warnings like "enum type mixed with other type" or something similar.

Comment: What is the purpose of `enum week var`? I don't know. After I have defined an `enum` the keyword `enum` will never appear later in my code. They are of type `int` and I use them as a handy way to define a set of values, that might otherwise be constants or `#define`s.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because any C book will answer this and we are not a tutoring service. Askers are required to understand the basics of the language they are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerated types are a useful abstraction for representing small sets of values that aren't necessarily ordered, or where arithmetic operations are not meaningful.  For example,

```
enum cartype { coupe, hatchback, sedan, suv };
```

Logically speaking, `cartype` has four values.  These values are not ordered relative to each other (what would the meaning of `sedan < suv` be?), there aren't any arithemtic operations defined on them (what would the meaning of `coupe + hatchback` be?), etc.

Basically, just another way of representing data, without bogging you down in details of that representation.